# Calculate difference of indices

Tags: java, programming-challenge, complexity

The [challenge](http://www.codechef.com/APRIL14/problems/ADIGIT) is to reconstruct an *n*-digit number using the following information:

> On each step, you choose an index *x* from 1 to *n*.  For all indices *y* (*y*
>   < *x*), you calculate the difference *b*<sub>*y*</sub> = *a*<sub>*x*</sub> - *a*<sub>*y*</sub>.
>
> You then calculate *B*<sub>1</sub> — sum of all by which are greater
>   than 0 and *B*<sub>2</sub> — sum of all by which are less than 0.
>
> The answer for this step is *B*<sub>1</sub> - *B*<sub>2</sub>.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains two integers *n* and *m*, denoting the number
>   of digits and number of steps. The second line contains *n* digits
>   (without spaces) *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *a*<sub>*n*</sub>.
>   Each of the next *m* lines contains a single integer *x* denoting the index for
>   the current step.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each of *m* steps print single number in a line - answer of the
>   step.

Can someone please help me optimize this code or provide a better, less time-consuming solution?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Chefs
{
    //BufferedReader in;
    DataInputStream in;
    PrintWriter out;
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> mymap=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    int a[],n,m,b1,b2;
    public Chefs()
    {
        //in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        out=new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
        readInput();
        calchef();
    }
    void readInput()
    {
        try
        {
            String digit=in.readLine();
            String split[]=digit.split("\\s+");
            n=Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            m=Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            a=new int[n];

            digit=in.readLine();

            for(int i=0;i<digit.length();i++)
                a[i]=digit.charAt(i);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void calchef()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {  
            try
            {
                b1=0;
                b2=0;
                int index=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                if(mymap.containsKey(index))
                {
                    int ans=mymap.get(index);
                    out.println(ans);
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<index-1;j++)
                    {
                        if(a[index-1]-a[j]>0)
                        {
                            b1+=(a[index-1]-a[j]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            b2+=(a[index-1]-a[j]);
                        }
                    }
                    int ans=b1-b2;
                    out.println(ans);
                    mymap.put(index,ans);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Chefs c=new Chefs();
        //long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        //System.out.println(totalTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) I would change the inner for loop this way (very little optimization, unlikely it will bring better performance)

```
int ans=0;
int y=index-1;
for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
{
    int diff = a[y] - a[j];

    if(diff > 0)
        ans += diff;
    else
        ans -= diff;
}
```

2) You never store ans in the map.

Comment: ya ya i forgot to add the updated code here,i missed that part,its added now.

Comment: even after ur code,it exceeds my 1sec time limit,cant it be further optimized